# MySQL: Getting a row number (ranking) for a specific row

Tags: mysql

I have a `users` table that has a column called `money_sent`. I want to order this table by `money_sent` in descending order, and then find out what "rank" a specific user has.

For example, only 111 people have spent more money than User 12392, so they would be rank 112.

How could I query this?

Answer (score 13):

How about:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE money_sent < (
    SELECT money_sent FROM users WHERE user = 'joe'
);
```

Comment: Great! A simple but effective idea!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Row,user, money_sent
FROM (SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS Row, user, money_sent 
       FROM table1 order by money_sent desc) 
As derived1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to get the user's row along with that user's rank, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT u1.*, COUNT(u2.user) 
FROM users u1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u2 ON (u1.money_sent < u2.money_sent)
GROUP BY u1.user;
```