# Fast mySQL leaderboard with player rank (& surrounding players)

Tags: mysql

I'm making a simple game, with leaderboard functionality (mySQL/PHP).

On game finish:

1. To Server: Player's score
2. From Server: Server, player's rank PLUS 5
   players directly above & below them
   in rankings

I'm not particularky confident the sever will handle the expected player traffic - so I want to do this right.

Which of the following approaches would work (and be fastest)?

- Alter Table? (slow when table is often modified?  how to get rank?)
- Simple row (rank) counter with ORDER BY? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504116/mysql-getting-a-row-number-ranking-for-a-specific-row)
- Simple row (rank) counter using WHERE clause faster? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293817/mysql-get-users-rank)

or have I missed a better solution?

Comment: Why do you need an alter table?

Comment: To keep the table sorted, ordered on score.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ALTER TABLE**
`ALTER TABLE` is to change the structure of the table.
You use it when you've made a mistake or you've changed your mind on how to do things.
If you dunno what it does, don't use it.

**INDEX**
An `INDEX` is to make sorting **faster**, **always** assign an index to columns that you use regularly in a `WHERE` clause or in an `ORDER BY` clause.
You can sort and select just fine *without* indexes, just slower.

**RANKING**
If you want to list highest ranking players on top then:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM players ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 25
```

Will give you the top 25 high score players, highest score first *(it sorts in reverse order* `DESC` *from high to low)*

**FANCY RANKING**

```
SELECT @rank:= 0; -- <<-- First run this query!

SELECT @rank:= @rank + 1 as rank, s.* FROM (
  SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM players ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 25  
) s; --<<-- than this one.
```

Oh and read up on basic SQL stuff.
Google for `SQL tutorial`

Good luck.

Comment: The "Fancy Ranking" in one query: `SELECT @rank:= @rank + 1 as rank, s.* FROM (
  SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM players, (SELECT @rank:=0) r ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 25  
) s`

Comment: @arnep, be carefull with initializing @rank inside the query, MySQL does not guarantee the order in which query parts are executed. If it executes in the wrong order your rank goes something like `(null,null,...,0)` for the first run and `(0,1,2,3,...,0)`for the second run, or even weirder orders :-).

Comment: do you have experience/documentation about this kind of "optimization"? The initialization of `@rank` is inside a subquery so this is assumed to be execued first ...

Comment: @arnep, I'm just saying don't make too many assumptions about the order in which MySQL executes the query. It's a complicated subject.

Comment: no need to write two separate queries. you simply do so. `SELECT @rank:= @rank + 1 as rank, s.* FROM (
  SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM players ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 25  
) s cross join (SELECT @rank := 0) r`