# Mysql SELECT query used to find postion

Tags: mysql

[image]

In the above table, `c` position is `3`.

Is there any function to find the position in Mysql?
[image]

**update**

Comment: row_id or row_number ? i am not sure of syntax..

Comment: Did you try these solutions? [MySQL Row Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number) and [MySQL: Getting a row number (ranking) for a specific row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504116/mysql-getting-a-row-number-ranking-for-a-specific-row)

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy: say user b,on total number he is second because second highest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: @user1051322 Why do you need the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
    SELECT x.user, 
       x.position,
       x.number
  FROM (SELECT t.user,
               t.number,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
          FROM TABLE t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      ORDER BY t.number DESC) x
 WHERE x.user = 'c'
```

You can then get his position from x.position

Comment: :Say there is one more record user d and his number is 45 then i should get position as 3 but your query will give me as 4 so,it is wrong.

Comment: @user1051322 I don;t understand why you are saying it's wrong. My query does not use the number column to determine row position in any way

Comment: :create a dummy table and i/p the data as i have given and input x.user = d,in db ,d ,number is 35.the o/p should be 3.third highest in the whole table

Comment: Ok now I get. I didnt know you wanted the data sorted as well. Well I added something to the query (ORDER BY t.number DESC). This should solve the issue

Comment: what does @rownum: means in mysql.Can you explain your query

Comment: @ROWNUM is a pseudo column, a pseudo column means that, the column actually does not exist in storage, whenever a query is executed, a new column is associated with the resulting set of rows, and the value contained is row number

Please could you explain you last statement more. I don't really understand

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘theposition’, t.* from mytable t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by t.USER desc;
```

Comment: :I'ii input the user id,it has to find the postion in the whole table and say for a particular user what is his position in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to add an id field. i don't know of any function to do that. you can select * and then in a script language search it or use a subquery. but i don't recommend that.

Comment: If the id is auto increment, it won't necessarily give you the position once you have deleted a row from the table.

Comment: @yankitwizzy:id is not auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
     @rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1 'RowNumber', 
     u.* 
FROM Users u, 
  (SELECT @rowNumber := 0) r
  ORDER BY u.User ASC
```

Comment: :See my above image.I'ii input the user.what is reonumber?